# Airpush new AirPlay 1.0 SDK Intergration

Tags: android, sdk, ads, airpush

I've been trying to add AirPush's new SDK but the ads are not showing(Smartwall).
I've successfully complied the apk but no results whatsoever.

Here is the main java file.. Please have a look and tell me what's wrong ?

```
package com.testappap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.zjxyo.erteehrt.AdCallbackListener;  //Add import statements
import com.zjxyo.erteehrt.AirPlay;


public class testappap extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private WebView mWebView;
    private AirPlay airPlay; // AirPlay 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        if(airPlay==null)
            airPlay=new AirPlay(null, null, false);
            airPlay.startSmartWallAd();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(airPlay!=null)
            airPlay.startSmartWallAd();
    }

    @Override   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

airPlay=new AirPlay(null, null, false);

First parameter cann't be null. their sdk requires Activity reference as a first parameter.

check this:  http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=AirSDK_1.0_for_Play_Store_Documentation#Step_3_-_Editing_Your_Main_File

Comment: Thanks.. Could you also please tell me how should i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

please use this:

airPlay=new AirPlay(this, null, false);

Comment: please explain it properly for better understanding of users.